# Lookup a csv file using python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to lookup below csv file and return the value from the field called 'datatype' passing mapping, transformation and portname as lookup ports.

```
Mapping    transformation   portname    datatype
m_TEST_1    EXP_test_1     field_1       nstring
m_TEST_1    EXP_test_1      field_2      date/time
```

Basically, I want to perform (`Select datatype from csv_file where mapping=? and transformation=? and portname=? )`

Currently , I'm looping through each row of the csv file to fetch the datatype. Is there any easy and better way to do it.

Below is the current code that I'm using.

```
            lkp_file = csv.DictReader(open(lkpfile))
            for row in lkp_file:
                if mapping.get('NAME')==row['Mapping']:
                    if frominstance==row['transformation']:
                        if fromfield==row['portname']:
                            fromdatatype=row['datatype']
                            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach you could have is a `csv.DictReader` and them some kind of transformation.

Is `(Mapping, transformation, portname)` unique?

If so you can do somehting similar to this:

```
import csv

d = {}
with open("path-to.csv", "r") as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")):
        d[(row['Mapping'], row['transformation'], row['portname'])] = row['datatype']
```

You will have to swap the delimiter as in my examplke I use commas and you do not have them in the text you gave us.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)?

Your csv file:
**example.csv**:

```
Mapping,transformation,portname,datatype
m_TEST_1,EXP_test_1,field_1,nstring
m_TEST_1,EXP_test_1,field_2,date/time
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
reqd_cols = df[(df.Mapping == 'm_TEST_1') & (df.transformation == 'EXP_test_1') & (df.portname == 'field_1')]
print(reqd_cols)

#     Mapping transformation portname datatype
# 0  m_TEST_1     EXP_test_1  field_1  nstring
```

Comment: yeah I can try that, but was wondering if I can do it with python built in packages and without looping.

Comment: For data visualization and manipulation, particularly those with `csv` files, `Pandas` gives you lot of advantage over other Python built in packages.